# Getting elevation of surface in a specific point from DEM?

Tags: arcpy, python, dem, elevation

In my python code, I have to get elevation of surface in given coordinates. I know about Extract values to points tool in ArcMap, but I can't use that since it is very time consuming for me because I do evolutionary calculation and have to use it many many times in my python code.

What I need is a module or tool that takes coordinates and DEM direction then gives a number as height. I don't want to deal with creating feature classes or any other unnecessary stuff.

If you know any tools or module which can help me, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to numpy Array, find out which indices your coordinates correspond to and fetch values from array:

```
import arcpy, os
import numpy as np

raster = r"C:\GIS\data\SomeDEMraster.tif"
coords = [[364764, 6283003],[383872, 6215199],[352822, 6257659]] #Or read from a csv file etc.
arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster)

def giveRasterValue(x,y,nparr): #Might be better to put the describe parts outside the function (since they are the same for the input raster) if you experience slow performance.
    r = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(raster,r'Band_1'))
    ex = r.extent.upperLeft.X
    ey = r.extent.upperLeft.Y
    h = r.meanCellHeight
    w = r.meanCellWidth
    ix = int(round((x-ex)/w,0))
    iy = int(round((ey-y)/h,0))
    return nparr[iy,ix]

for c in coords:
    print(giveRasterValue(c[0],c[1],arr))
```

Outputs:

```
22.611887
178.1588
-0.07274423
```